# ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

Why is oracle returning..

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 3: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_RULE_RANGE_ATTR' ORA-06550: line 9, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

When I've set all types and parameters according to the procedure specification.

#### The procedure specification

```
PROCEDURE add_rule_range_attr(
    "p_name" IN VARCHAR2,
    "p_entity" IN VARCHAR2,
    "p_attribute" IN VARCHAR2,
    "p_r_negate" IN NUMBER,
    "p_ra_comparer1" IN VARCHAR2,
    "p_ra_comparer2" IN VARCHAR2
);
```

Originally my code is running in an Oracle APEX environment where the parameters for the procedure are filled by input variables (e.g. `:PX_INPUT_NAME`), so there I've to make sure all variables I put in the parameter are the correct data type. However when calling the procedure, I use variables with default values corresponding to the requested data type for the procedure parameter.

#### Calling the procedure

```
brg_manager.add_rule_range_attr(
    p_name => v_name,
    p_entity => v_entity,
    p_attribute => v_attribute,
    p_r_negate => v_negate,
    p_ra_comparer1 => v_comparer1,
    p_ra_comparer2 => v_comparer2
);
```

Have a look at [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15920/8) for a working example.

Comment: `p_name` and `"p_name"` are not the same thing.

Comment: Don't use `"` when declaring objects. You're just needless creating a world of pain for yourself and any other poor blighter who has to use your schema.

Comment: The issue is simply that Oracle identifiers are not case-sensitive ... until you put double quotes around them. Or, more accurately, `p_name`, `P_Name`, and `P_NAME` are all regarded as `P_NAME`, while `"p_name"` is regarded as `p_name` (all in lowercase).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to omit`"` (procedure definition) or call it with `"` around parameter identifiers:

```
brg_manager.add_rule_range_attr(
    "p_name" => v_name,
    "p_entity" => v_entity,
    "p_attribute" => v_attribute,
    "p_r_negate" => v_negate,
    "p_ra_comparer1" => v_comparer1,
    "p_ra_comparer2" => v_comparer2
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8716d5401a183e274226cae271fc9209)**

---

From [Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) :

> Schema Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> **A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.**